# Labelling jitters with specific marker using seaborn

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have four different `label_list`. If the values from the second and third column from each of the `label_list` is the same, i would like to mark that point with a specific marker. 
For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['0', 0.3, 'gd','gd'],['0',0.2,'gf','gd'],['1',0.5,'gd','gd'],['1',0.1,'gf','gf'],['2', 0.9,'gd','gd'],['2', 0.1,'gf','gf'],
                   ['0', 0.8,'gd','gd'],['0',0.3,'gf','gf'],['1',0.3,'gd','gd'],['1',0.3,'gf','gf'],['2', 0.4,'gd','gf'],['2', 0.3,'gf','gf'],
                   ['0', 0.4,'gd','gf'],['0',0.4,'gf','gd'],['1',0.0,'gd','gf'],['1',0.9,'gf','gd'],['2', 0.7,'gd','gf'],['2', 0.4,'gf','gd']])

df.columns = ['label', 'score','hotel','hotel_1']

label_list = ['0', '1', '2','3']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
g=sns.boxplot(x='label', y='score', data=df, hue='hotel',dodge =True)
g=sns.stripplot(x='label',y = 'score',data=df, hue='hotel_1',dodge =False)
g.legend_.remove()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw the markers in two steps, once when the last columns are equal, once when they are different. As the default markers might be too small, a `size` parameter can be handy:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame([['0', 0.3, 'gd', 'gd'], ['0', 0.2, 'gf', 'gd'], ['1', 0.5, 'gd', 'gd'], ['1', 0.1, 'gf', 'gf'], ['2', 0.9, 'gd', 'gd'], ['2', 0.1, 'gf', 'gf'],
                   ['0', 0.8, 'gd', 'gd'], ['0', 0.3, 'gf', 'gf'], ['1', 0.3, 'gd', 'gd'], ['1', 0.3, 'gf', 'gf'], ['2', 0.4, 'gd', 'gf'], ['2', 0.3, 'gf', 'gf'],
                   ['0', 0.4, 'gd', 'gf'], ['0', 0.4, 'gf', 'gd'], ['1', 0.0, 'gd', 'gf'], ['1', 0.9, 'gf', 'gd'], ['2', 0.7, 'gd', 'gf'], ['2', 0.4, 'gf', 'gd']])

df.columns = ['label', 'score', 'hotel', 'hotel_1']

label_list = ['0', '1', '2', '3']
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
palette={'gd': 'steelblue', 'gf': 'darkorange'}
g = sns.boxplot(x='label', y='score', data=df, hue='hotel', dodge=True, palette=palette)
g = sns.stripplot(x='label', y='score', data=df[df['hotel'] == df['hotel_1']], hue='hotel_1',
                  dodge=False, marker='*', size=10, palette=palette)
g = sns.stripplot(x='label', y='score', data=df[df['hotel'] != df['hotel_1']], hue='hotel_1',
                  dodge=False, marker='D', size=7, palette=palette)

g.legend_.remove()

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: Setting `dodge=True` for both `stripplot`s and changing the `hue_order`:

```py
palette={'gd': 'steelblue', 'gf': 'darkorange'}
g = sns.boxplot(x='label', y='score', data=df, hue='hotel', dodge=True, palette=palette, hue_order=['gd', 'gf'])
g = sns.stripplot(x='label', y='score', data=df[df['hotel'] == df['hotel_1']], hue='hotel_1', hue_order=['gf', 'gd'],
                  dodge=True, marker='*', size=10, palette=palette)
g = sns.stripplot(x='label', y='score', data=df[df['hotel'] != df['hotel_1']], hue='hotel_1', hue_order=['gf', 'gd'],
                  dodge=True, marker='D', size=7, palette=palette)
```

[image: dodge=True]

Comment: Hi, I tried to incorporate your suggestion. There is a problem i encounter. The values from one `label` is plotted on an another  `label`. For example : The score `0.2` from group `gf` is plotted on group `gd`in label `0`.

Comment: Maybe it helps to set an explicit palette (as in the updated answer)? Or setting `dodge=True`?

Comment: I tried settling `dodge = True`. But the problem still persists.

Comment: Can you clarify with a very concrete example what you'd like differently? The blue diamond for `label=0`, `score=0.2`, where do you want it? Do you want `hue='hotel'` for the first stripplot (instead of `hue='hotel_1'`?

Comment: In the plot you have added, for the `label = 0`, the blue star at `0.8` belongs to blue bar, but its shown in the top of orange bar.

Comment: Could you please be more precise in defining WHY something belongs where? You want the stars at one side? And the diamonds at the other? And the color defined by 'hotel' or maybe by 'hotel_1'?